# Restrict Squid access to only one site

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid

How do I restrict access to only **one website** through my Squid proxy?

The following doesn't work...

```
acl amazon_ireland src 79.125.0.0/17
acl some_site url_regex google

http_access allow amazon_ireland
http_access allow some_site
http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at the squid FAQ, there is a perfect example for your setup.

[Squid FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Is_there_an_easy_way_of_banning_all_Destination_addresses_except_one.3F)

```
 acl GOOD dst 10.0.0.1
 http_access allow GOOD
 http_access deny all
```

if you want to match by domain-name

```
 acl GOOD dstdomain .amazon.ie
 http_access allow GOOD
 http_access deny all
```

Comment: I tried looking at the Squid FAQ too, but there's just so much in there! Thanks for finding this!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, where you can specify the source IP addres. And block specific sites such as youtube facebook

```
acl liberaip src 130.44.0.215
acl block url_regex -i youtube facebook
http_access allow liberaip !block
```

Comment: Smart answer! I would like to add: change to ***acl allow url_regex  ...*** AND change to ***http_access allow ipranges allow*** To allow only these site to the IP given. (reverse)

Comment: After revisiting this question. I noticed your comment is more suitable to OP question. =P